# Show Title only on Top in EXT JS

Tags: extjs

I want to show the title on Top, here is the code for same and please see the output below:

Data is coming but it overwrites the title , so is there anyway to show title separately on to the top, can anybody help?

```
items: {
    xtype: 'chart',
    animate: true,
    shadow: true,
    store: store,
    legend: {
        position: 'top',
        title: 'XYZ ....',
        renderer: function(storeItem, item) {


            this.setTitle(storeItem.get('startPeriod') + 'to ' + storeItem.get('endPeriod'));
        }

    },
    axes: [{
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['per01', 'per02'],
        title: false,
        grid: true,
        roundToDecimal: false
    },

    {
        title: 'XYZ...',
        position: 'top',
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'Bottom',
        fields: ['..'],
        label: {
            rotate: {
                degrees: 270
            }

        }


    }, ],

    series: [{
        //type: 'bar',
        type: 'column',
        axis: 'bottom',
        gutter: 80,
        xField: 'ou',
        //title: periodStr1,
        title: ['April-' + lastyear_graph1 + " to " + strMonth + "-" + selectedText_yr, 'April-' + year2 + " to " + strMonth + "-" + year3_graph1],
        yField: ['per01', 'per02'],
        stacked: false,
        tips: {
            trackMouse: true,
            width: 65,
            height: 28,
            renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                this.setTitle(String(item.value[1]));
            }
        }


    }]

}
```

Comment: "Top" of what? What gets overwritten and where is the output?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a title for the chart, you should set the title config of the chart and not the title config of the series. Title config of series is the human-readable name of the series which displayed in the legend.

```
items: {
    xtype: 'chart',
    animate: true,
    shadow: true,
    title: 'My Chart Title', //Set title here
    -------------------
    -------------------
}
```